# calculations based on matching keys' values in Ruby hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm making artist recommendation program that will match a hash showing artists that a user has seen live and how many times, against a hash showing artists that a given artist has shared a bill with and how many times. The match score is calculated based on these numbers. If a user has seen some artist x amount of times and a given artist has played with this artist at least once, like this:

```
user = {"artist7" => 3, "artist8" => 1}
artist1 = {"artist6" => 7, "artist7" => 7}

match = 0 

user.each do |k, v|
  if artist1[k]
    match += (1 - ((user[k] - artist1[k])/(user[k] + artist1[k])).abs)
  end
end
```

I have tried this out in irb and the value of `match` does not change.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? Doing so may discourage other answers and imo is inconsiderate to those still working on answers (not me). Many here wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection.

Comment: sorry, will wait longer in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your inputs are integers, so ruby uses integer division. It looks like that's likely to produce `1`, and `1 - 1` is zero. Add some `to_f` to your equation to use float division instead, e.g.:

```
match += (1 - ((user[k] - artist1[k]).to_f/(user[k] + artist1[k])).abs)
```